# All buttons in list returning same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several buttons in a row, all with class `add-btn`. When you click on one, I want to log the id of its encasing span. However, what I'm finding is that all buttons log the span of the first `add-btn` in the list.

```
$('.add-btn').click(function()
{
    var shop_name = $('.add-btn').closest('span').attr('id');
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.domain.com/includes/follow.php",
        data: {id: id, shop_name: shop_name},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

*follow.php:*

```
$shop_name = $_POST['shop_name'];
var_dump($shop_name);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `$('.add-btn')` inside the click handler with `$(this)`.

```
$('.add-btn').click(function()
{
    var shop_name = $(this).closest('span').attr('id');
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.domain.com/includes/follow.php",
        data: {id: id, shop_name: shop_name},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

What you're currently doing is getting the first `.add-btn` id.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Will accept when I can. Why does referring to the class directly mean that JS goes for the first one?

Comment: Because you're just querying the elements again when you do that instead of working with the one that was clicked.

Comment: If you were to do `$('.add-btn').height()` it would give you the height of the first one from the collection, which is kind what's happening here.